# Plot 2 images side by side for each for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm training a KNN model and I want to plot 2 images per for loop, as shown in the imagen below:

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1RCg.png)

At the left, I plot the boundary visualization of my model for a certain amoung of neighbours. At the right, I plot the confusion matrix.

To accomplish something along those lines I've written the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure()

for i in range(1,3):
    neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
    neigh.fit(X, y)
    y_pred = neigh.predict(X)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_pred,y)
            
    # Boundary
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
    visualize_classifier(neigh, X, y, ax=ax1) # Defined by me
    
    # Plot confusion matrix. Defined by sklearn.metrics
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2) 
    plot_confusion_matrix(neigh, X, y, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, values_format = '.0f',ax=ax2)
    
    ax1.set_title(f'Neighbors = {i}.\nAccuracy = {acc:.4f}',
             fontsize = 14)
    ax2.set_title(f'Neighbors = {i}.\nAccuracy = {acc:.4f}',
             fontsize = 14)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.figure(i)
    plt.show()
```

The visualize_classifier() function:

```
def visualize_classifier(model, X, y, ax=None, cmap='Dark2'):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    
    # Plot the training points
    ax.scatter(X.iloc[:, 0], X.iloc[:, 1], c=y, s=30, cmap=cmap, # Changed to iloc.
               clim=(y.min(), y.max()), zorder=3, alpha = 0.5)
    ax.axis('tight')
    ax.set_xlabel('x1')
    ax.set_ylabel('x2')
#     ax.axis('off')
    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(*xlim, num=200),
                         np.linspace(*ylim, num=200))
    Z = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]).reshape(xx.shape)

    # Create a color plot with the results
    n_classes = len(np.unique(y))
    contours = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, alpha=0.3,
                           levels=np.arange(n_classes + 1) - 0.5,
                           cmap=cmap, clim=(y.min(), y.max()),
                           zorder=1)

    ax.set(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
```

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuWJc.png)

[What I get. Continues...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tlc2t.png)

As you can see, only the first loop is plotted. the second one is not plotted and I can't figure out why.

Furthermore, I have the same title for the plot at the right and at the left. I would like to have only one on top of both, how can this be accomplished?

Now, you might be wondering why do I need to do this and the answer is that I would like to see how the boundaries change depending on the number of neighbors. It's just to get a visual sense of KNN algorithm.

Any suggestion would be pretty much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work. What I had wrong was the first line inside the for loop. I assigned `plt.figure(i, figsize=(18, 8))` to the variable `fig`.

```
for i in range(1,30):
    fig = plt.figure(i, figsize=(18, 8))
    sns.set(font_scale=2.0) # Adjust to fit
    neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
    neigh.fit(X, y)
    y_pred = neigh.predict(X)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_pred,y)
    
    # Boundary
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
    visualize_classifier(neigh, X, y, ax=ax1) # Defined by me
    
    # Plot confusion matrix. Defined by sklearn.metrics
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2) 
    plot_confusion_matrix(neigh, X, y, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, values_format = '.0f',ax=ax2)
    
    fig.suptitle(f'Neighbors = {i}. Accuracy = {acc:.4f}',y=1)
plt.show()
```

For the title I used: `fig.suptitle(f'Neighbors = {i}. Accuracy = {acc:.4f}',y=1)`

[image: Results]